# Is it bad for SEO to have a URL with nothing on it?

Tags: google, wordpress, url, web-crawlers

I have a WordPress site and for a very complicated reason I have to set some post type's template to empty file. Nothing.

Which means I have a URL on my site (let's say: `example.com/postype/the-best-post/`) which displays nothing (it doesn't only display nothing it's also really empty, like if you view the source, no code at all).

So is it bad for my site?

And if it is do i have another alternative that would make it alright (some way to say to Google robots.  I'm letting you know that this is a empty page and you have no reason to index it so don't punish me please?!)

Note:
This is isn't a duplicate of webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/106931/… because it's about pages with html, just with no content and this is about pages with no html at all.

Comment: You tagged this as "Google" so I'm assuming you are asking if it is bad for Google search engine optimization.

Comment: This is isn't a duplicate of https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/106931/do-empty-pages-or-pages-with-no-content-affect-seo because they are talking about page with html, just with no content and i'm talking about pages with no html at all (as i really tried to explain clearly in my question).

Comment: They ask about both and the answer is correct for either case.

Comment: It doesn't. he says there "realize that there is no meaningful content" (there is content), "search result pages of the internal website search with zero search results" (there is content), and so on... and in the answer there is no one recall of the html being empty also.