# SEO for pages with no content like cart, checkout, or "my account"

Tags: seo, content, soft-404, yoast

How do you optimize pages with no content for search engines.  I have pages that are functional, but have no content like cart, checkout, "my account".

I am using Yoast SEO

Comment: See also: [Do empty pages or pages with no content affect SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/106931/do-empty-pages-or-pages-with-no-content-affect-seo)

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters! ***How do you optimize pages with no content for search engines.*** Why would you want to do this? These pages have no value for search. I do not see the point. Cheers!!

Answer (score 7):

Why is there a need to optimize these pages?

I mean, they don't serve any purpose. They don't create any sales. In fact, even huge companies like Amazon defer from this, it's quite the contrary, they ask the [robots.txt](https://www.amazon.com/robots.txt) to block search engines from indexing these pages. If you google keywords like "amazon checkout" Amazon has optimized a [help page](https://www.amazon.in/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=200534030) that they want you to see instead of their actual checkout page.
[image]

Still, if you want to optimize these pages to rank(for any reason) you can:

1. Add some content or "help" section right on the checkout page and optimize it for keywords like "{your-company-name} checkout", "how to check out at {your-website-name} etc.
2. Add a few images with screen captures of the checkout process and steps and optimize them(with alt text and captions for the same keywords as mentioned above.
3. Add the page to your sitemap.xml.
4. Remove it from robots.txt (if it's there) and remove the "meta noindex" tag.
5. Let customers access it directly if they enter the URL www.your-website-name.com/checkout.

Comment: OK thanx, I am fairly new with SEO, and was just wondering what to do with them, thanx again!